# Não consigo ler a primeira linha de url

Tags: java, android, url

Boa noite.
Apesar de não descobrir qual é o erro não consigo obter a primeira linha do ficheiro que está na url quando esta aplicação é utilizada por versões superiores a api 10 pois a api 10 funciona bem.
porque será?

```
Integer valor;
TextView texto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BarraTextView);
    texto.setText("Verificando novas atualizações");
    try {
        valor = getUrlContents("http://exemplo/versao.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (valor > 111)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder confirma = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        confirma.setTitle("Aviso");
        confirma.setMessage("Existe uma nova versão deseja atualizar agora?");
        confirma.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
            {
                Intent DownloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://exemplo/aplicacao.apk"));
                startActivity(DownloadIntent);
                System.exit(0);
                finish();
            }
        });
        confirma.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
            {
                texto.setText("Iniciando a aplicação");
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                LoginActivity();
            }
        });
        confirma.create().show();
    }
    else
    {
        texto.setText("Iniciando a aplicação");
        LoginActivity();
    }
}

public void LoginActivity()
{
    Intent StartLoginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(StartLoginActivity);
    finish();
}


private static Integer getUrlContents(String theUrl) throws Exception
{
    Integer valor = 0;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf8"));
        valor = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return valor;
}
```

}

Comment: Olá. Seja bem-vindo ao SOPt. Qual é o conteúdo do arquivo localizado naquela URL? Qual é o erro observado? Esclareça melhor o problema. Aproveite e faça o nosso [tour], caso não tenha feito.

Comment: desde já obrigado pela ajuda.
sim já fiz a tour.
o ficheiro txt apenas tem 112 escrito.
quando a aplicação é iniciada num android api 10 versão 2.3.7 o programa lê o 112 e dá ordem true ao if mas quando iniciado em android mais recentes dá espaço em branco e dá ordem else.
o programa sendo o mesmo não entendo porque não funciona da mesma maneira em todas as versões.
à noite posso colocar um print screen de dois emuladores para ver que tem reações diferentes.